# Python flask API Return the cookies but set in browser

Tags: python, python-3.x, angular, cookies, flask-restful

I have an application in which the python flask API and angular frontend is used I'm able to set cookies and receive in frontend header but unable to fetch the value as shown in below images

the code for python flash is as follows

```
 response.set_cookie('token', secret_token, max_age=900, samesite='Lax')
response.set_cookie('region', user.MMUCode)
response.headers.add('Access-Control-Allow-Headers',
                     "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, x-auth")
return response
```

Here in angular the code is as follows

```
return this.httpClient.post<any>(apiUrl + APIRoutes.GenerateOTP, data,
  { observe: 'response' }).pipe(map(response => {
      console.log(response.headers.keys()); // all header names
      return response.body;
    }))
```

But the response header is having the cookies as shown in below images but not getting set as cookies in browser

[image: Image end response headers with cookies]

[image: Image for Cookies not set in browser]

Please help me with this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Add a sentence before you add it to the response: cookie.setpath("/");

Comment: Where do I do it? In flask or in python